How to loop to take an input and print an array of struct
I am quite confused on how to loop through an array of struct to take an input and store it, afterwards print all of the inputs from the struct.
I have this code in which I manually access the index of the array and it does work:
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    Person struc
        name db 10 DUP(0)
        password db 10 DUP(0)
    Person ends

    people Person 10 DUP(<>)

    prompt db 'Enter your name: ', 0
    prompt2 db 13, 10, 'Enter password: ', 0
    res db 13, 10, 'Your name is: ', 0
    res2 db 13, 10, 'Your password is: ', 0
.code

include io.mac

main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, 0
    ; First person (index 0)
    PutStr prompt
    GetStr people[0].name
    PutStr prompt2
    GetStr people[0].password
    PutCh 0Ah

    ; Second person (index 1)
    PutStr prompt
    GetStr people[20].name
    PutStr prompt2
    GetStr people[20].password
    PutCh 0Ah

    ; Third person (index 2)
    PutStr prompt
    GetStr people[40].name
    PutStr prompt2
    GetStr people[40].password
    PutCh 0Ah

    ; Print first person's info (index 0)
    PutStr res
    PutStr people[0].name
    PutStr res2
    PutStr people[0].password
    PutCh 0Ah

    ; Print second person's info (index 1)
    PutStr res
    PutStr people[20].name
    PutStr res2
    PutStr people[20].password
    PutCh 0Ah

    ; Print third person's info (index 2)
    PutStr res
    PutStr people[40].name
    PutStr res2
    PutStr people[40].password
    PutCh 0Ah

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

main endp
end main

But the problem is I don't want to manually input all of that so I tried to do a loop to make things easier... it didn't though.
Here is my code:
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    Person struc
        name db 10 DUP(0)
        password db 10 DUP(0)
    Person ends

    people Person 10 DUP(<>)

    prompt db 'Enter your name: ', 0
    prompt2 db 13, 10, 'Enter password: ', 0
    res db 13, 10, 'Your name is: ', 0
    res2 db 13, 10, 'Your password is: ', 0
.code

include io.mac

main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov cx, 3
    mov si, 0

    loop_input:
        PutStr prompt
        GetStr people[si].name
        PutStr prompt2
        GetStr people[si].password
        PutCh 0Ah

        add si, size Person ; size = 20
        loop loop_input

    mov cx, 3
    mov si, 0
    loop_output:
        PutStr res
        PutStr people[si].name
        PutStr res2
        PutStr people[si].password
        PutCh 0Ah

        add si, size Person ; size = 20
        loop loop_output

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

main endp
end main

This is the output when I manually accessed the index.
This is the output when I used the loop.

View the data inpeople when loop_input terminated. It looks as if macros PutStr and GetStr clobbered indexregister si.

The only difference I see in the 2 codes is the SI register. In the first code you did not use it, you used values to access the memory address.I don't know how PutStr and GetStr are implemented, probably in io.mac, but it seems like they are changing the SI register.

In io.mac the GetStr and PutStr macro's are defined as:

GetStr  MACRO   string1, buffer_size, extra
   IFB     <string1>
     %OUT  ERROR: Missing string parameter in GetStr macro.
     EXITM
   ENDIF
 
   push    CX       ;; CX is used for buffer size
   IFB     <buffer_size>
     %OUT  WARNING: Missing string length parameter in GetStr macro.
     %OUT           Maximum string length of 80 is used.
     mov   CX,81    ;; 80 + 1 for CR
   ELSE
     mov   CX,buffer_size
   ENDIF

   IFNB    <extra>
     %OUT  WARNING: Redundant parameters in GetStr macro - ignored.
   ENDIF
  
   push    AX
   mov     AX,OFFSET string1
   call    proc_GetStr
   pop     AX
   pop     CX
   ENDM



PutStr  MACRO   string, extra
   IFB     <string>
     %OUT  ERROR: Missing string parameter in PutStr macro.
     EXITM
   ENDIF

   IFNB    <extra>
     %OUT  WARNING: Redundant parameters in PutStr macro - ignored.
   ENDIF
   
   push    AX
   mov     AX,OFFSET string
   call    proc_PutStr
   pop     AX
   ENDM


Although I still haven't seen what's in proc_GetStr and proc_PutStr, seeing that even the AX register gets preserved, I think it's safe to assume that all registers get preserved in the end.
What worries me is their use of OFFSET as in mov AX,OFFSET string1 and mov AX,OFFSET string. This needs an operand that is known at assembly time. Your people[0].name is fine but your people[si].name is not, because at assembly time it is not known what the SI register will contain. Had these macro's used lea AX, string1 and lea AX, string your program would probably have worked.
Personally, I would edit the io.mac text file and solve it that way.


GetStr people[si].name
PutStr prompt2
GetStr people[si].password


You didn't specify the optional second macro argument to GetStr. Because it defaults to 81 and considering that your fields are limited to just 10 bytes, it would be safer to write:
GetStr people[si].name, 10
PutStr prompt2
GetStr people[si].password, 10

